# Post directly on user wall HTTP/1.0 400

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I make facebook application using facebook guide

When user allow application access than the index page redirect it to tst.php which directly post on user wall

I use the below code in index.php:

**index.php**

```
<?php 

require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(    
     'appId' => 'app_id',  
     'secret' => 'app_secret',  
     'cookie' => true,
)); 

$app_id = app_id;

$canvas_page = 'http://apps.facebook.com/tstsample/tst.php';

$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" .
            $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . 
            "&scope=email offline_access publish_stream";

$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);   

$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
} else {
     echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
} 

?>
```

And below is the code which I use in tst.php which use to directly post on user wall:

**tst.php**

```
<?php

$feedurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/134875956586326";
$ogurl = "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=134875956586326"; 
$app_id = “134875956586326”; 
$app_secret = "app_secret";

$mymessage = urlencode("Hello World!");

$access_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token"; 
$parameters = "type=client_credentials&client_id=" .  
$app_id . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret;
$access_token = file_get_contents($access_token_url . 
                "?" . $parameters);

$apprequest_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/feed";
$parameters = "?" . $access_token . "&message=" . 
              $mymessage . "&id=" . $ogurl . "&method=post";
$myurl = $apprequest_url . $parameters;

$result = file_get_contents($myurl);
echo "post_id" . $result;

?>
```

And after i run the application two errors occur

1. I see the access allow page than it stops on index page
2. After manually going on the tst.php as I mentioned in the above code, I receive PHP errors

Below are the errors:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_credentials&client_id=�134875956586326�&client_secret=606636c88cd434c5140986d8472fc639) 
             [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
                 HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /home5/onkhuras/public_html/escribir/tstsample/tst.php
                     on line 14

Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/feed?&message=Hello+World%21&id=http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=134875956586326&method=post) 
             [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
                 HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /home5/onkhuras/public_html/escribir/tstsample/tst.php
                     on line 21
post_id
```

How do I resolve these two errors?

**Note: I get these two codes from Facebook which I use in index.php and txt.php**

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? why two files? and is this a canvas page (Facebook App)?! Please update your question and provide answers to these questions

Comment: @ifaour

post directly  on user wall

When user allow application access than the index page redirect it to tst.php which directly post on user wall

yes this is the convas page facebook application using iframe

thank you

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue currently, and there is no guidance anywhere as to what is wrong, the URL clearly isn't the issue as manually going to the address created yeilds the exact same address.

Answer (score 0):

Check the authentication guide again - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/.

You need the code returned by /dialog/oauth to get an access_token from https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token

Comment: i already read the facebook guide and than use these above code and comma its not necessary

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (the second error message) and got it resolved by using my app id for $ogurl like this (the last few lines in your tst.php file):

```
...
$apprequest_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/feed";
$parameters = "?" . $access_token . "&message=" . 
          $mymessage . "&id=" . $app_id . "&method=post";
$myurl = $apprequest_url . $parameters;
$result = file_get_contents($myurl);
echo "post_id" . $result;
?>
```

In my case that lead to posting the message to the app wall.